# Почему ищется не та таблица?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Я начинающий в ASP.NET Core MVC.

Решил для практики написать сайт для  гостиницы. В любой гостинице есть номера, а номера делятся по классу комфорта (люкс, полулюкс, улучшенный и т.д.). В папке Models я описал модели для номеров под одним общим классом `RoomModel`:

```
    public class RoomModel
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RoomName { get; set; } 
    }
```

Подключился к локальной бд MS SQL Server, добавил в сервисы контекст бд - всё как положено.
Контекст получаю в контроллере:

```
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public AdminController(RoomContext context)
        {
            DBAdmin.SetContext(context); // Передаю контекст в специальный класс для работы с БД
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(DBAdmin.SelectAllData(RoomsType.Lux)); // Получаю данные из определённой таблицы (с люкс номерами) в виде списка List<RoomModel> и отдаю в представление
        }
    }
```

Контекст БД `RoomContext`:

```
    public class RoomContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<RoomModel> LuxRooms { get; set; } // таблица для люксов

        public DbSet<RoomModel> JuniorSuiteRooms { get; set; } // таблица для номеров с классом "Полулюкс"
        public RoomContext(DbContextOptions<RoomContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
```

Моя БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для работы с БД я решил сделать отдельный класс `DBAdmin`:

```
    public static class DBAdmin
    {
        private static RoomContext context;
        private static Dictionary<RoomsType, DbSet<RoomModel>> roomsTables = new Dictionary<RoomsType, DbSet<RoomModel>>(); //с помощью этого списка я проверяю входящий тип номера (люкс или полулюкс) с помощью перечисления типов номеров и выдаю соответствующую таблицу

        public static void SetContext(RoomContext cont)
        {
            context = cont;
            roomsTables.Add(RoomsType.Lux, context.LuxRooms);
            roomsTables.Add(RoomsType.JuniorSuite, context.JuniorSuiteRooms);
        }
        public static List<RoomModel> SelectAllData(RoomsType rtype) // rtype просто содержит одно из значение enum RoomsType, с которым будет сопоставляться нужная таблица
        {
            var rooms = roomsTables[rtype];
            return rooms.ToList(); // Возвращаю все значения таблицы в виде списка
        }
    }
```

В чём у меня проблема - у меня возникает следующая ошибка: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Invalid object name 'RoomModel'`
. Я так понимаю, список roomsTables возвратил таблицу с именем `RoomModel`, которой у меня нет и не должно быть. Почему так?

P.S. Если убрать из контекста `RoomContext` таблицу `DbSet<RoomModel> JuniorSuitRooms` или `LuxRooms`, то всё заработает.

Comment: Для чего такие сложности? Добавьте свойство RoomsType в модель.

Comment: Два `DbSet` закрыты одним и тем же типом `RoomModel`, что является абсурдом. А как  `DbSet` будет отличать комнаты свои от комнат другого `DbSet` если они ссылаются на одну и туже таблицу? По какому признаку можно отличить запись про комнату Lux от записи JuniorSuite если обе эти записи находятся в одной и той же таблице и между ними нет ни одного отличительного признака?

Comment: @Bulson, получается чтобы работать с этими таблицами, мне нужно создать классы под каждый из типов номеров и уже вписывать их в DbSet? Или же не парится и просто всё в одну таблицу записать). Я думал, что за указатель на таблицу отвечает имя свойства с типом DbSet, а оказывается нужен ещё и разный тип. Спасибо за понятный ответ!

Comment: @4per, я просматривал предложенный вами вариант записи в бд (все типы номеров в одну таблицу, с указанием нового столбца с типов номера), но мне такой вариант показался не совсем практичным, удобным и красивым.